# Identify the empty line in text file and loop over with that list in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a file which has the following kind of data

```
A 1 2 3 
B 2 2 2

c 2 4 5

d 4 5 6
```

From the above file I want to execute a loop like ,

three iteration where first iteration will have A,B elements 2nd iteration with c elements and 3rd with d. so that my html table will look like

```
Week1    |  week2    |   week3
----------------------------
A 1 2 3  |  c 2 4 5 | d 4 5 6
B 2 2 2
```

I found this in SO [catch multiple empty lines in file in tcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026753/catch-multiple-empty-lines-in-file-in-tcl) but I'm not getting what I exactly want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using arrays:

```
# Counter
set week 1
# Create file channel
set file [open filename.txt r]

# Read file contents line by line and store the line in the varialbe called $line
while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
    if {$line != ""} {
        # if line not empty, add line to current array with counter $week
        lappend Week($week) $line
    } else {
        # else, increment week number
        incr week
    }
}
# close file channel
close $file
# print Week array
parray Week

# Week(1) = {A 1 2 3} {B 2 2 2}
# Week(2) = {c 2 4 5}
# Week(3) = {d 4 5 6}
```

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/lc9cnL)

Comment: I'd use `struct::matrix` for this sort of thing, especially as the `report` package would then handle the printing easily enough.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for the solution. Can you add some comment lines to understand more

Comment: @Aroon Added :) I hope it helps